# pytest - add assertions to all or marked test functions

Tags: python, metaprogramming, pytest

I have common assertions performed on a fixture (named `obj` here) at the end of most test functions, like:

```
assert obj.is_empty
assert obj.no_errors
```

How can I append such steps to each test function or only marked ones so that, steps:

- will work with `pytest.mark.parametrize`,
- will report **Failure** (not **Error**) when common assertions fail?

Comment: I might just make a fixture that checks these various assertions then pass the object as a parameter to that fixture.

Comment: @shuttle87 It will return **Error** on failures instead **Failure** because fixtures are setup/teardowns.

Comment: Any reason you can't just use fail instead of assert? https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-fail

Comment: @shuttle87 Because `pytest.fail()` doesn't make difference when called in fixture it still gives an **Error**. Have you tested your solutions or I get the wrong idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I personally don't like the idea of running hidden assertions in tests (*explicit is better than implicit*), this is surely doable in `pytest` by implementing your own [`pytest_runtest_call`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_runtest_call) hook. A simple example:

```
# conftest.py
import pytest


class Obj:

    def __init__(self):
        self.is_empty = True
        self.no_errors = True


@pytest.fixture
def obj():
    return Obj()


def pytest_runtest_call(item):
    item.runtest()
    try:
        obj = item.funcargs['obj']
        assert obj.is_empty
        assert obj.no_errors
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Example tests:

```
import pytest


def test_spam(obj):
    assert True

def test_eggs(obj):
    obj.is_empty = False
    assert True

def test_bacon(obj):
    obj.no_errors = False
    assert True

@pytest.mark.parametrize('somearg', ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
def test_parametrized(obj, somearg):
    assert True
```

Running the test yields:

```
$ pytest -sv
================================== test session starts ==================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.7.3, py-1.5.4, pluggy-0.7.1 -- 
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow, inifile:
plugins: cov-2.5.1
collected 3 items

test_spam.py::test_spam PASSED
test_spam.py::test_eggs FAILED
test_spam.py::test_bacon FAILED
test_spam.py::test_parametrized[foo] PASSED
test_spam.py::test_parametrized[bar] PASSED
test_spam.py::test_parametrized[baz] PASSED

======================================== FAILURES =======================================
_______________________________________ test_eggs _______________________________________

item = <Function 'test_eggs'>

    def pytest_runtest_call(item):
        item.runtest()
        try:
        obj = item.funcargs['obj']
>           assert obj.is_empty
E           assert False
E            +  where False = <conftest.Obj object at 0x105854ba8>.is_empty

conftest.py:20: AssertionError
______________________________________ test_bacon _______________________________________

item = <Function 'test_bacon'>

    def pytest_runtest_call(item):
        item.runtest()
        try:
            obj = item.funcargs['obj']
            assert obj.is_empty
>           assert obj.no_errors
E           assert False
E            +  where False = <conftest.Obj object at 0x105868198>.no_errors

conftest.py:21: AssertionError
========================== 2 failed, 1 passed in 0.05 seconds ===========================
```

Comment: TYVM. I had no idea which hook to use and also couldn't find `funcargs` attribute in docs. I think `item.get` is better than `try-except`, so you can edit comment if you agree. Do you know where to find good code examples with pytest hook usage? Documentation alone doesn't help to know their capabilities.

Comment: Yeah, I agree the `funcargs` dict handling in the example is questionable :-) As for hook examples, I'm afraid the best source is the [`pytest` code itself](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest), although it's sometimes hard to extract stuff you really need from their code. It gets better after a while, though. The source code for `pytest` plugins is also helpful sometimes. Glad I could help!

Comment: The places you mentioned were ones I used to seek knowledge. I'm glad to hear that I wasn't doing it in a wrong way, and sad that there is no better way than source code and "tribal knowledge".